# Неясность с методом GET в PHP

Tags: php, методы

Здравствуйте, я хотел бы задать вопрос! Не понимаю , почему у меня не работает, я все правельно сделал, Method GET у меня не работает! я щас вам пришлю код , посмотрите пожалуйста , но я не понимаю че там я не правельно сделал!Код который в файле exit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exit</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1251">
        <meta name="description" content="<?echo $row['meta_d'];?>">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?echo $row['meta_k'];?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
        <? include ("blocks/header.php");?>     
        <? include ("blocks/sidebar.php");?>
        <?php
            $db = mysql_connect("localhost","ilez","0060606");
            mysql_select_db("testsite",$db);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,description,author,date,header FROM tokio",$db);
            $row_tokio = mysql_fetch_array($result);

         ?>

            <div class="content">
                <?php
                    do{
                        printf(
                                "<h1><a class='header' href='view.php?d='%s'>%s</a></h1>
                                <p>%s</p><p>%s , %s</p>",$row_tokio["id"],$row_tokio["header"],$row_tokio["description"],"Author : ".$row_tokio["author"],'The date : '.date('Y-t-m')
                                );
                    }
                    while($row_tokio = mysql_fetch_array($result));

                 ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? include ("blocks/footer.php");?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Код который в файле View.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1251">
        <meta name="description" content="<?echo $row['meta_d'];?>">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?echo $row['meta_k'];?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <?
                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                    {
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                    }
                ?>
        <? include ("blocks/header.php");?>
        <? include ("blocks/sidebar.php");?>
            <div class="content">

                <?php 
                    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","ilez","0060606");
                    mysql_select_db("testsite",$db);
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM tokio WHERE id='$id'",$db);
                    $row_tokio = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    echo $row_tokio['text'];
                ?>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <? include ("blocks/footer.php");?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Объясните где моя ошибка, или денвер некорректно работает?

Comment: .

    do{
       printf(...
    }
    while($row_tokio = mysql_fetch_array($result));

Что случится, если первый `mysql_fetch_array()` вернет false?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1><a class='header' href='view.php?d='%s'>
```

опечатка в генерации ссылки строке href. Я думаю, должно быть view.php?**id**='%s'

Comment: ну это буквы там роль не играет даже если там стоит b или c это чисто буквы

Comment: Наверное , денвер глючит((

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id']))

буквы имеют определённую ценность :)) в данном случае в слове **id** очень нужна буква **i**

Comment: Я так пробовал, на в данном случае где if(isset($_GET['id'])) там слово id взято из базы данных а именно  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,description,author,date,header FROM tokio",$db); , ну я и так пробовал , как и ты говорил, может денвер не корректно работать не знаешь Павел?

Comment: Как это роль не играет? Вы отсылаете гетом переменную d, а потом пытаетесь получить содержимое переменной id, которой нет, т.к. есть только $_GET['d']

Comment: Роль играет тот id который в базе данных где mysql_query("SELECT id
и на самом деле ?id=%s это же ?id = $row_tokio['id'] и потом если существует в файле exit переменная id которая находится в базе данных то именно эту переменную мы во втором файле присваиваем к переменной $id , и смотря какой у нее id (1 или 2 или 3) файл view.php отображает определенную информацию , когда я говорил что там роль не играет , я имел определенную роль, а так я пробовал и так , т.е в view.php?id=%s , но это не сработало, не знаю как решить

Comment: Раз ты пробовал и d и id... По симптомам лечить не получилось. Надо сдать анализы :)

В каком месте и какая ошибка возникает? Включи режим "показывать все ошибки" и покажи все сообщения, которые выводятся

для этого вставь строку `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL) ?>` в самом начале скриптов exit.php и view.php

а после этой команды в view.php напиши `<?php var_export($_GET); ?>`

и ещё покажи последние записи из протокола error.log

Comment: @ilez,

> ну это буквы там роль не играет даже если там стоит b или c это чисто буквы

позволю себе продолжить: *там вообще роль не играет какой код написан*